# Excel How to calculate exchanged price according to monthly exchange rate

Tags: excel, exchange-server, currency

I would like to get formula which can calculate currency value according to specified currency exchange rate in specified month.
If date purchase is 14/02/2013 then get currency exchange from february and use to divide USD price to get EUR price.
Please see example here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AjSYvGqCVD59dDU0ME4waEl6d21Uend5TE5JSnZVMUE&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this formula:

```
=D2*OFFSET($A$1,MONTH(C2),1)
```